# change font css on negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the font color to red when the number is  below 0. green when above. I've managed to get the entire row to go red thanks to a stackoverflow answer but can't manage to give it to the font itself.

the `<?php echo $coin_gain; ?>` displays a number that can negative.

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $coin_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $coin_price; ?></td>
    <td class="status"><?php  echo $coin_gain; ?>%</td>
</tr>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".status").each(function(){
            var value = parseInt ( $( this).html() );
            if (value < 0){
                $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $coin_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $coin_price; ?></td>
    <td class="status"><?php  echo $coin_gain; ?>%</td>
</tr>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".status").each(function(){
            var value = parseInt ( $( this).html() );
            if (value < 0){
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You simply need to remove the parent selector to target the cell itself rather than the row.

Comment: well don't i feel sheepish. Just done this and was ready to delete the question. prompt reply cheers

Comment: No probs. I've done a quick edit - as I noticed you wanted the font color to change. I've edited to reflect that.

Comment: thanking you kindly. have a safe and merry christmas

Comment: @Mark.S as a side note. You can set the default font color to be green in your stylesheet, and then just alter the font color whenever you encounter a number below 0. This will save you having to do an if-else statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target the cell, remove `.parent()` :

```
if (value < 0){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
} else {
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
}
```

When you add `.parent()` you target the containing element of your cell (`<td>`), which is the row (`<tr>`)

Comment: just tried it then checked back on my question ready to delete. could I do an else statement for it to be green when above 0?

Comment: It's easier and more semantic to set the default color to green and just set the font to red whenever you encounter a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

If you output with PHP, then process class with PHP too:

For font color it's `color: #000000` and not `background-color`

```
<?php $isPositive = $coin_gain >= 0; ?>
<tr style="background-color: <?= $isPositive ? 'green' : 'red'; ?>>
    <td><?= $coin_name; ?></td>
    <td><?= $coin_price; ?></td>
    <td class="status" style="color: <?= $isPositive ? 'green' : 'red'; ?>><?= echo $coin_gain; ?>%</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I think it would affect the performance even if by a little to use server side approach to constantly refresh the style of that particular variable. Javascript is better suited in this case, eitherway nice answer.

Comment: @Highdef If OP is already looping coin data, then adding few more sentences would not hit performance, while JS approach can slow down user actions because everything must be re-looped and re-evaluated.

Comment: Well, I guess that's relative then on what exactly the OP is doing. In general, JS is faster considerably than PHP(on the same hardware), though if cache is used on the server side it could increase the performance considerably but yeah, it's all relative to what the OP tries to perform.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $coin_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $coin_price; ?></td>
    <td class="status"><?php  echo $coin_gain; ?>%</td>
</tr>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".status").each(function(){
            var value = parseInt ( $( this).html() );
            if (value < 0){
                // this will change the color of font 
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```